# PHP preg_replace() with a variable giving me a warning error

Tags: php

This command gives me a warning, and I would like to know how to fix it.

```
$countDaily = preg_replace($demande_portabilite, "", $last_request);
```

This is the error I'm getting :
 Warning: preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in /var/www/html/PortabiliteForm.php on line 22

Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to surround your pattern with some delimiters. Usually the delimiter used is `/`. So for your code:

```
$countDaily = preg_replace("/" . $demande_portabilite . "/", "", $last_request);
```